# Can I remove my custom recovery?

Tags: root-access, nexus-5

I'm in a weird predicament with my Nexus 5. I rooted easily when I first got it then 5.1 was rolling out and I really wanted to upgrade and did, then I was able to reapply the root access but didn't *really* use anything required root access enough to care. Now my OTA is ready for 5.1.1 so I clicked install (when the notification popped up) and it went into the recovery bit which is the twrp mod and cuts of the rest of the install process. I think. Can i remove twrp without losing my phones data and apply this update or is there an easier work around perhaps? My boot loader is also unlocked, I just really can't be bothered to flash a new ROM (although cataclysm looks fun) and then sort out all my apps and settings again.

Answer (score 3):

Download the 5.1 [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerheadlmy47i), Then extract the `tgz`, you will find a `zip` file, copy `recovery.img` to the same directory that have the `fastboot` file

Reboot to `bootloader` and connect to PC then open `terminal` or `cmd` 'Windows' and type that:

`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`

then enter, then wait to finish and now everything is good!

Comment: After extracting out recovery image (recovery.img), you can also flash it using apps like [Flashify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify) or [Rashr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mkrtchyan.recoverytools) (they will need root access), in case you arent comfortable with using adb and fastboot.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end however I went ahead and used a Cataclysm ROM, I think it's worked out for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just flash the recovery and you won't lose any data.