# replacing twrp with recovery.img fails for nexus 6

Tags: updates, recovery-mode, unrooting

I have a nexus 6 with TWRP and a stock ROM (6.0.0). I decided to update via OTA. However, for this I need to flash the recovery.img as stated in this [anwser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110535/can-i-remove-my-custom-recovery). Following the instructions there I've done the following steps (i'm usign linux):

1. Downloaded the factory image from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) for Nexus 6 (6.0.0)
2. extracted the recovery.img and moved it to a separate folder
3. booted into bootloader and connected with my workstation.

the device was detected correctly:

```
ola@thinkstation:~$ fastboot devices
ZX1G427VQJ  fastboot
ola@thinkstation:~$
```

4. I flashed the recovery.img and rebooted

everything went fine:

```
ola@thinkstation:~$ fastboot devices
ZX1G427VQJ  fastboot
ola@thinkstation:~$ fastboot flash recovery /home/ola/temp/android/recovery.img 
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (8915 KB)...
OKAY [  0.351s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.298s]
finished. total time: 0.648s
nicolas@thinkstation:~$ fastboot reboot
rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.001s
ola@thinkstation:~$
```

I then rebooted and tried to download the 6.0.1 via OTA. The download was successful. However, after restarting and the beginning of installing I get an Android icon and the message "Error". That's it. I then tried to boot in to bootloader and do a recovery mode where I get an error "No Command". So I reflushed the recovery.img leading to the same result. Normal booting works perfectly fine. Whats causing the error?

Comment: Did you do any modification to the system (root, Xposed, everything counts)?

Comment: @AndyYan it is rooted.

Comment: [My answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/144737/96277) should be able to help you to understand the reason behind the error. Also, give us the exact error message.

Comment: @user8 System mode or systemless? System mode root will kill OTAs.

Comment: @AndyYan I have superSu v2.78 systemless if I'm not completely wrong. How else can I check?

Comment: @user8 Weird if nothing else is done. +1 for awareness. There _might_ be OTA zips available over at XDA for you to flash via custom recoveries.